# How to call a classic ASP.NET Page from a MVC Action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, report

I am using StructureMap with ASP.NET MVC. I have a requirement where I need to show a ReportViewer and for that I am using a classic ASP.NET page. The problem is when I am trying to redirect from the action I am getting following issue:

The IControllerFactory 'StructureMapControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Reports.aspx'.

Can someone please guide me on how do I call a classic asp.net page from an action and get rid of this error?

Comment: Considering its classic asp in the same project and you're using MVC, it might be easy to port it over to MVC?

Comment: Classic asp != asp.net.  Which do you actually mean?  I know you MVC people think you're new and cool, but asp.net is still a current language....

Comment: @ck: Classic ASP people use VBScript's "<>" instead of "!=".

Answer (score 3):

You need to map a route for your *classic* page so that the MVC engine skips it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to redirect the request to a 'classic' ASP.NET web form from the controller action, you might call `HttpContext.Response.Redirect("URL")`. The routing engine by default will resolve files that exist on the disk. No need to map new routes.